# Given a string Opentext print Open1ex2 i.e replace t's in the string with the count of t

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
  char str[]="OpenText";
  int i=0,strlen,count=0;
  while(str[i]!='\0')
    i++;
  strlen=i;

  for(i=0;i<strlen;i++)
  {
     if(str[i]=='T' || str[i]=='t')
     {
       count++;
       str[i]=count;
     }
  }
  printf("%s",str);
}
```

I got output :Openex

I am not getting the desired output, please help me out.

I want to get Open1ex2 as output i.e  for the given a string Opentext I want to get  Open1ex2 as output i.e replace t's in the string with the count of t

Comment: Are we to guess what your desired output is?

Comment: No, I want to get Open1ex2 as Output.

Comment: 'str[i]=count;' fail.  numeric value != ASCII representation.  Add the count to '0'

Comment: `count=0;` ====> `count='0';`

Comment: What should happen it there are more than 9 `t,T` in the `str[]`?

Comment: @chux 'A', obviosuly ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you are assigning count to the Str[i], you are not converting integer to character. Just add '0' to the count to covert integer into character.

```
#include<stdio.h>
    void main()
    {
      char str[]="OpenText";
      int i=0,strlen,count=0;
      while(str[i]!='\0')
        i++;
      strlen=i;

      for(i=0;i<strlen;i++)
      {
         if(str[i]=='T' || str[i]=='t')
         {
           count++;
           str[i] = '0' + count; // Only change to convert integer to character
         } 
      }
      printf("%s", str);
    }
```

Cheers!!

Comment: OP is unclear on input: `"tttt_tttt_tttt"`, as this will "overflow" `'0' + count`.